# closure with unowned keyword is retaining my object

Tags: swift, closures

Basically I have following

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var myClosure = { [unowned tableView] in 
     ...
   }
}
```

I ultimately want to have access to my tableView in my closure without creating a retain cycle.

Writing this, my tableView given by the method parameter gets retained by my closure.

I probably missing something here about closure ownership, but what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my code had actually a *nested closure*. The closure where I added my capture list was in the second closure.

Moving it to my first closure solved my problem.